# Opening laravel on apache

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I want to get the laravel site up and running so I can check how it looks. I've used `php artisan serve` but it points me to the localhost. I've tried the other options like `--host` and `--port` but it still doesn't work.

Right now all I see is the directory root if I go into the folder. I know that the public is the one with the index.php but when I tried to go into it, the server responds with a page isn't working.

Comment: Is your php version >= 5.6.4?

Comment: php version is 5.6.28. I can't seem to find anything regarding this issue either.